# How to reboot a WSGI application

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

There are a lot of implementation for the WSGI specification, like mod_wsgi and Phusion Passenger. Now I have bought a shared Python host which uses Phusion Passenger. AFAIK there is no standard for how to reboot a WSGI application, so each implementation has its own way. For example in Phusion Passenger just touching the `restart.txt` file does the trick. My question is: Is there any way to reboot a WSGI application regardless of what implementation is used using Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no standardized way to reboot a WSGI application that works across all implementations. As you mentioned, each implementation has its own way of restarting the application.

In general, the way to restart a WSGI application is to cause the underlying WSGI server to reload the application. The exact mechanism for doing this will depend on the specific WSGI server being used.

If you're using a shared Python host that uses Phusion Passenger, then the recommended way to restart the application is to touch the `restart.txt` file, as you mentioned. This file is used by Phusion Passenger to signal that the application should be restarted.

If you're using a different WSGI server, you'll need to consult the documentation for that server to determine the appropriate way to restart the application. For example, if you're using mod_wsgi, you might need to restart the Apache server in order to reload the application.

In general, it's best to consult the documentation for your specific WSGI server to determine the appropriate way to restart the application.

Comment: Thanks for your comforting answer. Is it possible to find out what WSGI server the web server is using through Python or a shell script?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to find out what WSGI server the web server is using through Python or a shell script.
In Python, you can use the `environ` dictionary provided by the WSGI specification to access information about the server environment. Specifically, you can look at the `SERVER_SOFTWARE` key, which contains the name and version of the server software. If the server is using a WSGI server, this information should include the name of the WSGI server.

Comment: Shell Script: curl -I http://example.com/ | grep Server